# Get Function name inside a loop pass

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am pretty amateur in LLVM. I am trying to write a loop pass in which I need to know which function I'm in. Is there any way to find that?
I want to do this in the following *runOnLoop* function:

```
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop *L, LPPassManager &LPM) override {

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
StringRef Name = L->getHeader()->getParent()->getName();
```

Comment: Thank you, That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @NGC1977 you are welcome, in case the answer suits you can consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).